# Tables landscape

Tags: tables

I have the following table

```
\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}         & a     & b     & c \\
  %  \midrule
    1     & 835344,615874329 + 400069,959720461i & 1107439,53335601 + 476686,978014529i & 905159,269217538 + 673912,871163914i \\
    2     & 832524,719513344 + 396241,014807440i & 1104704,13980475 + 470232,023098608i & 902697,366045792 + 667885,450741210i \\
    3     & 653193,492308602 + 414438,396024549i & 947291,747098637 + 493556,580041306i & 1221033,69315666 + 515918,714008828i \\
    4     & 637500,000000000 + 395087,015731978i & 900000,000000000 + 435889,894354067i & 1187500,00000000 + 390312,374899900i \\
  %  \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{sidewaystable}
```

[image]

How can I put two tables or more on the same page as shown below?

[image]

Comment: Please edit your post and complete your code so that it will compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put two `tabular`s inside the same `sidewaystable` environment like

```
\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{}\label{}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
content
\end{tabular}
%
\caption{}\label{}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
content
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

Full example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating,booktabs}
\begin{document}
  \begin{sidewaystable}
  %% first tabular
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}         & a     & b     & c \\
   \midrule
    1     & 835344,615874329 + 400069,959720461i & 1107439,53335601 + 476686,978014529i & 905159,269217538 + 673912,871163914i \\
    2     & 832524,719513344 + 396241,014807440i & 1104704,13980475 + 470232,023098608i & 902697,366045792 + 667885,450741210i \\
    3     & 653193,492308602 + 414438,396024549i & 947291,747098637 + 493556,580041306i & 1221033,69315666 + 515918,714008828i \\
    4     & 637500,000000000 + 395087,015731978i & 900000,000000000 + 435889,894354067i & 1187500,00000000 + 390312,374899900i \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabelgg}%
  %% second tabular
  \caption{Add caption for second table}
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}         & a     & b     & c \\
    \midrule
    1     & 835344,615874329 + 400069,959720461i & 1107439,53335601 + 476686,978014529i & 905159,269217538 + 673912,871163914i \\
    2     & 832524,719513344 + 396241,014807440i & 1104704,13980475 + 470232,023098608i & 902697,366045792 + 667885,450741210i \\
    3     & 653193,492308602 + 414438,396024549i & 947291,747098637 + 493556,580041306i & 1221033,69315666 + 515918,714008828i \\
    4     & 637500,000000000 + 395087,015731978i & 900000,000000000 + 435889,894354067i & 1187500,00000000 + 390312,374899900i \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I dont know why but in my code I had a error in this line ` \caption{Add caption for second table}`. The problem is that my code this very large and I donot know where to look.  The error is "package flowtrow error". Do you know what can I do ?

Comment: @Freitas: Reduce your code by deleting line by line and produce minimal code that produces the error and ask a new question with that minimal code.